# Why are my new Canon 80D RAW files are unreadable on my computer and on Photoshop CS5?

Tags: canon, adobe, canon-80d

Has Adobe CS5 stopped supporting new Cameras? I was lucky I shot RAW+JPEG so I was able to atleast have JPEGs quickly. Does that mean Adobe is pushing me to subscribe to Adobe CC?

Is there any free alternative to be able to open these new RAW files into Photoshop and Lightroom?

Comment: Or maybe just [search on "photoshop tax"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=photoshop+tax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very old versions of Lightroom or Photoshop to support newer cameras Adobe recommends to convert native, proprietary RAW files to DNG format.

Snippet from [an Adobe support page](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/why-is-my-camera-not-supported.html)

> **What if I own an older version of Photoshop or Lightroom?**
>
> You do not have to buy a new version of Photoshop or Lightroom just to
>   get the latest camera support.
>
> Adobe provides backwards compatibility for the latest cameras for free
>   in Photoshop CS, CS2, CS3, CS4, CS5, and CS6 as well as Lightroom 1,
>   2, 3, 4, and 5, through the [Adobe DNG Converter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adobe-dng-converter.html). With this tool, you
>   can easily convert camera-specific raw files from supported cameras to
>   a more universal DNG raw file.

Another snippet explaining need of DNG format -

> **Why is DNG necessary for legacy version support?**
>
> The difficulty with supporting Adobe Camera Raw plug-in updates for
>   legacy versions of Photoshop and Lightroom is that camera
>   manufacturers are creating new proprietary raw formats each time they
>   come out with a new camera—and new cameras are coming out faster and
>   in greater volume.
>
> It’s untenable to keep updating previous versions of the Adobe Camera
>   Raw plug-in and support new cameras/raw formats in a timely fashion.
>
> Using the DNG converter is the fastest way to deliver backwards
>   compatibility to all customers (CS1–CS6; Lightroom 1–5; Photoshop
>   Elements 3–13; as well as third-party apps that support DNG).
>
> Put simply, the DNG Converter allows Adobe to support the most
>   possible customers and cameras.

You can download the DNG convertor tool from this link - [Adobe Digital Negative Converter](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adobe-dng-converter.html)

Comment: Thanks @Harshil Sharma I will try this one, but it's one additional step for me

Comment: @AmritBharadwaj you can create a script to chain DNG conversion and import in lightroom. This way you'll only have to perform one action - run this script.

Comment: Be aware that some of the raw sensor data an the "maker notes' section of the EXIF data are discarded when a Canon .cr2 file is converted to DNG. If you only plan to use Adobe products to edit the images this will not be a concern because Adobe ignores all of that information even when working with an original .cr2 file. But other application can, and some do, use that information.

Comment: I did all the suggestions but I can't open RAW (CR2) files in Photoshop CS6 or Lightroom 5.7.1 at all. The only option I have is to convert to DNG now. Does DNG looses out on Image Quality in any way I noticed the file size of the converted file is much smaller than the RAW file.

Comment: @MichaelClark  Do you know how can I show Thumbnails in Windows for the newer RAW (CR2) files, I am only able to see Thumbnails from my older camera 600D but not from 80D. I have a Windows 10 based laptop

Comment: You have other options. For instance you can use Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* to process your raw files. I find it much easier to control fine gradations of color with *DPP* than with Adobe products. Once you've finished your work in *DPP* then you can export as TIFF or JPEG to use in PS.

Comment: My Windows 10 machine currently shows thumbs for .cr2 files from all of my EOS cameras. But the newest one I currently have is a 7DII. When I first updated to W10 only .cr2 files from 2 of the three cameras I use the most (5D2, 5D3, 7D2) were showing thumbs. After the latest update from W10 (to ver. 1607) all of them now show the preview thumbs. You might just need to be patient until windows includes compatibility for .cr2 files from the 80D in a major update version.

Answer (score 2):

You most probably need to update Camera Raw. This is the component that allows Photoshop and Lightroom to read raw files from various cameras. It exists separately because otherwise they'd have to update Photoshop and Lightroom for every new camera that comes out.

[According to Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html#Canon]), the 80D is supported since Camera Raw version 9.5. Check yours ([this page shows how](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/troubleshoot-camera-raw-photoshop-photoshop.html)) and if it's older than 9.5, update it.

**Edit:** turns out that Photoshop CS5 supports Camera Raw up to version 6.7. You need Photoshop CC to install Camera Raw newer than 9.1.1. Thanks to [Robin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13908/robin).

Comment: It isn't compatible, CS5 is only compatible up to version 6.7. https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html